# How to vent a 1/4" drain tube?

Tags: drain, dehumidifier

I have a dehumidifier which is hooked to a 1/4" drain tube. The drain tube is not functioning because I think there is some kind of vacuum or pressure differential thing happening. I know that plumbing lines are "vented" to prevent this kind of vapor lock from occurring. If that is the problem, how do I vent a 1/4" drain tube?

The symptom of what happens is that if I disconnect the tube, so there is just a 1/4" orifice in the back of the dehumidifier is that water drips out of the orifice. If I connect the tube to the orifice and to the drain pipe, the the water flows a little bit, but eventually the flow stops.

Comment: See also: [Capillary action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_action)

Answer (score 2):

Drain tubes do not require a vent for normal operation.

What drain tubes do need is a direct path down, not horizontal, with nothing touching the end of the tube and no “trap”.

With a small drain like that a simple 1/4” raise in elevation in the tube creates a trap. This same issue happens on large evaporators and will back up a larger tube even with a 8’-10’ drop after the horizontal section and stop the flow.

If you had a system that was working and after a few months it starts backing up it could be plugging up with dust and mold in the drip pan and plugging the tube, or a simple spider web across the tube opening. These are things that can stop the flow of a normal gravity drain.

Comment: It is a new system. There is a distance of 6 feet between the dehumidifier and the port on the drain pipe. I did have the tube hanging down below the level of the pipe, so it was making a trap. I don't want sewer gas to be coming into the basement through this tube, though, right? So, don't I need a trap? Or are you saying water will get stuck in the tube and block gases, even without a trap?

Comment: If you need a trap do not use the tube to make it. If tied into your home sewer create the trap and allow this to drip into the trap. Do not allow the end of the tube to be submerged. 

Have you ever seen a steel disk with holes punched floating on water? The water tension is enough to float steel, a small air bubble will stop your system from draining and that’s what traps do create a lock. So you have to have a break so the water can drip into the trap, if dumping into a floor drain there is a trap below but going directly into the system you are correct you need a trap but not on the 1/4”

Comment: Sounds like that "port" is intended only as a cleanout access point and you shouldn't be draining into it in the first place.  See if you can't place the dehumid elsewhere, maybe feed a floor drain, for example, or a basement sink if you have one.